# java.lang.StackOverflow al usar recursividad

Tags: java, algoritmos, recursión

Estoy haciendo una función que imprime el porcentaje del proceso, el cual termina cuando el contador llega a la cantidad meta, pero siempre me tira el siguiente error :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at pruebas.Bucles.recursion(Bucles.java:88)`

El error lo imprime muchas veces, aquí les dejo mi clase:

```
public class Bucles {

    private static final long META = 1000000000;
    private long porcentaje;

    public void probar(){
         porcentaje = META / 100;
        recursion(0);
    }



    private void recursion(long i) {
       // System.out.println(i);
        if (i < META) {
            if (i > porcentaje && i % porcentaje == 0) {
                System.out.println("proceso recursión : " + i / porcentaje + " %");
            }

            recursion(i++);// <----- Está es la linea 88
        }
    }
}
```

---

Hice el cambio tal como me indican de cambiar el postincremento:

```
private void recursion(long i) {
    // System.out.println(i);
    if (i < META) {
        if (i > porcentaje && i % porcentaje == 0) {
            System.out.println("proceso recursión : " + i / porcentaje + " %");
        }

        recursion(++i);// <----- Está es la linea 88
    }
}
```

Si imprimo el valor de `i` (descomento la linea) ocurre algo muy raro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema principal es lo que se comenta en [la respuesta de mmartinez7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/75235/227) (usa `++i` no `i++`). Ahora, lo que sucede es que tienes muchas llamadas almacenadas en la pila de llamadas, por lo cual sucede el mismo error: `StackOverflowError`. Esto sucede por la cantidad de veces que estás llamando al método `recursion`, el cual está limitado por el valor de `META`.

Soluciones:

1. Reduce el tamaño de `META` a 100, por ejemplo. (La más efectiva)
2. Si quieres mantener el tamaño actual de `META`, necesitarás incrementar el tamaño del stack mediante el parámetro `-Xss`. Ejemplo `-Xss100m` para decir que el stack tiene un tamaño de 100 MBs. (No deseado, esto es índice que tu aplicación tiene algo extraño).

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estas utilizando el [postincremento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java) en tu llamada recursiva. El postincremento implica aumentar el valor en 1 para la siguiente instrucción.

Tu programa podría ser escrito asi y sería equivalente:

```
    private void recursion(long i) {
        if (i < META) {
            if (i > porcentaje && i % porcentaje == 0) {
                System.out.println("proceso recursión : " + i / porcentaje + " %");
            }

            recursion(i);
            i++
        }

}
```

Basicamente tu i vale siempre 0 y recién será incrementado cuando salgas de la llamada recursiva, lo cual nunca sucederá ya que `0 < META`

Lo correcto para lo que tratas de hacer sería utilizar el preincremento:

```
    private void recursion(long i) {
        if (i < META) {
            if (i > porcentaje && i % porcentaje == 0) {
                System.out.println("proceso recursión : " + i / porcentaje + " %");
            }

            recursion(++i);
        }

}
```

Comment: usé ++i y ocurré exactamente lo mismo, estoy imprimiendo el valor de i y ocurre algo muy raro, actualizé la pregunta

Comment: No es exactamente el mismo problema. Utilizando postincremento tu "i" nunca incrementaba su valor. En este caso, estas incrementando "i" y a su vez llegando a 5259 llamadas recursivas. El tamaño del stack no es infinito, por ende hay un límite de llamadas recursivas, depende de la memoria virtual asignada.

Comment: con el i++ también avanzaba el contador, también lo probé